# Apply like operator in split command to filter data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a csv file data as below

```
InsuranceId,                 InsrancerName ,     Date
Ins_Trns_Raj_A2020_07,       Rajesh Kumar,       2020-06-07 23:59:43
Ins_Trns_Nar_B2019_07,       naresh Yadav,       2019-06-07 23:59:43
Ins_Trns_Ant_C2018_07,       Antony,             2018-06-07 23:59:43
Ins_Trns_Vin_B2020_07,       Vinod,              2020-07-07 22:59:32
Ins_Trns_Man_C2019_07,       Manu,               2019-07-07 22:59:32
Ins_Trns_Man_X2019_07,       Raju,               2015-07-07 22:59:32
Ins_Trns_Man_Y2019_07,       Rishi,              2016-07-07 22:59:32
```

Reading the above csv into dataframe

```
dfInsId = pd.read_csv("InsurancerInfo.txt")
```

Split the data based on position

```
dfInsId['InsuranceId'].str.split('-',expand=True)
```

Values are splatted into 5 parts like : Ins    Trns   Raj   A2020   07

Any way to keep like operator or to identify data based of 3rd field of  "_" delimiter  and filter data into different dataframe

dataframe_1 have data where 3rd field of "_" starts with "A"

```
InsuranceId,                 InsrancerName ,     Date
Ins_Trns_Raj_A2020_07,       Rajesh Kumar,       2020-06-07 23:59:43
```

dataframe_2 have data where 3rd field of "_" starts with "B"

```
InsuranceId,                 InsrancerName ,     Date
Ins_Trns_Nar_B2019_07,       naresh Yadav,       2019-06-07 23:59:43
Ins_Trns_Vin_B2020_07,       Vinod,              2020-07-07 22:59:32
```

dataframe_3 have data where 3rd field of "_" starts with "C"

```
InsuranceId,                 InsrancerName ,     Date
Ins_Trns_Ant_C2018_07,       Antony,             2018-06-07 23:59:43
Ins_Trns_Man_C2019_07,       Manu,               2019-07-07 22:59:32
```

other than A,B,C,D,E rest other data into different dataframe

Comment: There is always only one letter?

Comment: @jezrael .. Thanks a lot for the reply .. There might me multiple letters but i will be having starting with A , B, C,D  & E . so how can i specify these 5 letters  and divide them into 5 different dataframes ? other than these 5 letters , remaining data should go into other dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#extract filter letters from splitted values by `_` for 4th list
s = dfInsId['InsuranceId'].str.split('_').str[3].str[0]

#specified groups letters
vals = ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E']  

#filter groups
mask = s.isin(vals)
dfs = dict(tuple(dfInsId.groupby(s[mask])))
# print (dfs)
```

---

```
print (dfs['A'])
             InsuranceId                  InsrancerName                  Date
0  Ins_Trns_Raj_A2020_07                    Rajesh Kumar  2020-06-07 23:59:43

print (dfs['B'])
             InsuranceId                  InsrancerName                  Date
1  Ins_Trns_Nar_B2019_07                    naresh Yadav  2019-06-07 23:59:43
3  Ins_Trns_Vin_B2020_07                           Vinod  2020-07-07 22:59:32
```

All not matched data filter by inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_other = df[~mask]
print (df_other)
             InsuranceId                  InsrancerName                  Date
5  Ins_Trns_Man_X2019_07                            Raju  2015-07-07 22:59:32
6  Ins_Trns_Man_Y2019_07                           Rishi  2016-07-07 22:59:32
```

Comment: other than mentioned A,B,C,D,E remaining data go into other dataframe

Comment: @jezreal : If i don't have any key words among these A,B,C,D,E  is there any way i can handle null handle